# SQL Server - Trigger when Stored Procedure is Deleted

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I want to do a trigger for when a Stored Procedure is deleted in the database, I have this code which doesn't server my needs since it is for an alter and creation of a Stored Procedure.

```
Create trigger CheckTrigger
On database
For create_procedure, alter_procedure
```

Can you guys give me some guidance in which code could I use for the trigger when a Stored Procedure is Deleted from the Database??

Comment: what would you do with a trigger? Maybe an audit is a better option?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/auditing/sql-server-audit-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: AFAIK this is not possible.

Comment: @Asdfg yes it it, it's (unsurprisingly) `DROP_PROCEDURE`: [DDL Statements That Have Server or Database Scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/ddl-events?view=sql-server-ver15#ddl-statements-that-have-server-or-database-scope)

Comment: @Larnu: Thank you. I did not know that. I guess the answer will be something like `CREATE TRIGGER safety   
ON DATABASE   
FOR CREATE_PROCEDURE, DROP_PROCEDURE,
AS   
   PRINT 'Stored Proc Created or Dropped!'`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is resolved with the link to the documentation posted in the comments.